# Check if a char is in a 2D array in java

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array, chess

I have been working on my homework of creating a simple chess program.

The chessboard is a **2D array**, named board. The pieces are all single chars like R,Q,K, and empty space is filled with a ' ' char, so a space.

```
public static char[][] board;
```

The method get should return the char or whatever is there on the coordinate (x,y).

```
 public char get(int x, int y) {
        if(x < board[0].length && x >= 0 && y < board.length && y >= 0){
            return board[x][y];
        }
        else
            return '\0';
    }
```

And the problem is that my program of evaluating who is the winner is not working as expected.

This program checks whether the **king of each team is still in the chessboard**, so the board array.

It should return 0 if both are still alive, 1, if only the white king is alive, and 2 if only the black king is alive.

I have made a program, or at least tried to make one, that goes through each coordinate and checks if there is a character 'K', which represents the white king, and 'S', the black king.

I have set the boolean kingIsAlive to false, so that if there is no K or S found in the array, it remains false.

Though, my code at the bottom, with the if and else that returns 0,1 or2, has the error, that **kingWhiteIsAlive is always false** and **kingBlackIsAlive is always false.**

So, I think my program of turning the kingIsAlive boolean to true is not working at all....

**The errors I got is:**

White should have won => expected: <1> but was: <-1>

No one should have won => expected: <0> but was: <1>

And after a couple of hours trying, I gave up and decided to ask here.

```
public int decideWinner(){
    boolean kingWhiteIsAlive = false;
    boolean kingBlackIsAlive = false;

    for(int y = 0; y < board.length;y++){
        for(int x = 0;x < board[0].length;x++){
            if(get(x,y) == 'K'){
                kingWhiteIsAlive = true;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < board.length;j++){
        for(int i = 0;i < board[0].length;i++){
            if(get(i,j) == 'S'){
                kingBlackIsAlive = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if(kingWhiteIsAlive && kingBlackIsAlive){
        return 0;
    }
    else if(kingWhiteIsAlive && !kingBlackIsAlive){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(!kingWhiteIsAlive && kingBlackIsAlive){
        return 2;
    }
    else
        return -1;
}
```

return -1 is for a test case that there are no kings from both teams.

Comment: It's working for me. Is `board` defined correctly, and where are you defining it?

Comment: Your code looks to me like it should work.  Maybe your `board` array doesn't store what you think it should.  I'd recommend stepping through this with a debugger to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your code & it's running perfectly, perhaps the problem is in your board initialization?

Try to debug your code by showing the actual content of the array at the beginning of `decideWinner` function.

I've used this initialization for the board, if it might help.

```
public void initBoard() {
  board = new char[8][8];
  // Init pawns
  for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
    board[j][1] = 'P';
    board[j][6] = 'P';
  }
  // Rooks
  board[0][0] = 'R';
  board[7][0] = 'R';
  board[0][7] = 'R';
  board[7][7] = 'R';

  // Knights
  board[1][0] = 'N';
  board[6][0] = 'N';
  board[1][7] = 'N';
  board[6][7] = 'N';

  // Bishops
  board[2][0] = 'B';
  board[5][0] = 'B';
  board[2][7] = 'B';
  board[5][7] = 'B';

  // Queens
  board[3][0] = 'Q';
  board[4][7] = 'Q';

  // Kings
  board[4][0] = 'K'; // White
  board[3][7] = 'S'; // Black

  // Empty space
  for (int y = 0; y < board.length; y++) {
    for (int x = 2; x < 6; x++) {
      board[y][x] = ' ';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find a king, you need to interrupt your search. You can do it by a `break` statement.

```
for(int y = 0; y < board.length;y++){
    for(int x = 0;x < board[0].length;x++){
        if(get(x,y) == 'K'){
            kingWhiteIsAlive = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
for(int j = 0; j < board.length;j++){
    for(int i = 0;i < board[0].length;i++){
        if(get(i,j) == 'S'){
            kingBlackIsAlive = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```